# Android - Google Maps API Heatmap with fixed radius in meters

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

The Heatmap Overlay for the Android Google Maps API renders the radius in pixels, which means that by zooming in and out the radius gets bigger and smaller.

I need a heatmap with fixed radius (e.g. in meters instead of pixels) that does not rescale when zooming in and out.

Is there any possibility to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In googlemap api, get scale data. In UI you have the legend which states the map scale. Something like this -  (check in google maps bottom right I'm talking about 2000Ft thing below)

[image]

You know cm length of the phone screen, you know the pixels in complete width,so

cm(phoneScreen) --> cm/pixel ratio --> pixel radius to cm radius.

you can deduce using some maths I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

As for my opinion you can use setRadius() method to change the radius of heatmaps location in response to changed zoom. Something like this:

```
    int DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL = 10;
    int ZOOM_STEP_FOR_RADIUS = 2;

    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .data(mList)
            .setRadius(DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL)
            .build();
    mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));

    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener({
        @Override
        void onCameraIdle() {
            float newZoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

            mProvider.setRadius(DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL + newZoom * ZOOM_STEP_FOR_RADIUS)
            mOverlay.clearTileCache();
        }
    });
```